# I can't send array to .net core mvc Controller with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am sending data to controller with xhr in an api project. I can run it without any problem when there is no array in the data. However, when I add an array to the incoming json, I get a null error. Can you please help?

**CONTROLLER**

```js
 [HttpPost]
        [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
        [Route("adminHome")]
        public string adminHome([FromBody]userSettingsModel model)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(model.userEmail);
            return "View()";
        }
```

**AJAX**

```js
var usersettings = {
    "userEmail":item.querySelector('.zfc-query-mail').textContent,
    "timeBanned":item.querySelector('.usertimebanned').value,
    "userBanned":item.querySelector('.userbannedi').checked,
    "userCategory":[]
}

item.querySelectorAll('.service-item').forEach(es => {
    if (!es.querySelector('.bg-danger')) {
        var servicesettings = {
            "startService":es.querySelector('.startservice-time').value,
            "endService":es.querySelector('.endservice-time').value,
            "maxlogin":es.querySelector('.maxlogin-i-i').value,
            "sessionTime":es.querySelector('.sessions-times').value,
            "sleep":es.querySelector('.timesleep-i').value,
            "feedback":es.querySelector('.feedback').value,
            "categoryId":es.querySelector('.categoryId').value
        }
        usersettings.userCategory.push(servicesettings)
    }
});
console.log(usersettings)
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = '/zfc/adminHome';
http.open('POST', url, true);

http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        console.log(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(JSON.stringify(usersettings));
```

**MODEL 1**

```js
public class userSettingsModel
    {
        public string userEmail { get; set; }
        public DateTime timeBanned { get; set; }
        public bool userBanned { get; set; }
        public userCategoryDetailsModel[] userCategory { get; set; }
    }
```

**MODEL 2**

```js
    public class userCategoryDetailsModel
    {
        public string categoryId { get; set; }
        public DateTime endService { get; set; }
        public DateTime sleep { get; set; }
        public DateTime startService { get; set; }
        public string feedback { get; set; }
        public int maxlogin { get; set; }
        public int sessionTime { get; set; }
    }
```

**ERROR**

```js
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at zfc.webapi.Controllers.zfcController.adminHome(userSettingsModel model) in C:\Users\mderv\Desktop\zfc\zfc.webapi\Controllers\zfcController.cs:line 142
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)     
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

[Ajax .NET Core MVC send JSON Array to Controller using Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63164862/ajax-net-core-mvc-send-json-array-to-controller-using-ajax)
I've looked into this question as well but couldn't find a solution. Can you please help?

Comment: The problem was that the data that was supposed to come from the form was string instead of number. Number inputs give value of type strinf. When I updated it to Number() , the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

/* check your foreach loop and item values */

```
var usersettings = {
        "userEmail":"E1",
        "timeBanned":"E2",
        "userBanned":"E3",
        "userCategory":[]
    }

   
           servicesettings = {
                "startService":"T1",
                "endService":"T2",
                "maxlogin":"T3",
                "sessionTime":"",
                "sleep":"timesleep-i",
                "feedback":"feedback",
                "categoryId":"categoryId"
                
            }
   usersettings.userCategory.push(servicesettings);

    console.log(usersettings)
  ------------------Result-------------------
```

{
"userEmail": "E1",
"timeBanned": "E2",
"userBanned": "E3",
"userCategory": [
{
"startService": "T1",
"endService": "T2",
"maxlogin": "T3",
"sessionTime": "",
"sleep": "timesleep-i",
"feedback": "feedback",
"categoryId": "categoryId"
}
]
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).